# How to prevent 'automatically sort object property in alphabetical order' in Angular post/get Request

Tags: angular

I have dynamic header in the grid and i need to implement JSON response in exact order which is coming from backend but in the get/post request object keys get sorted in alphabatical order due to this table column header and value got mismatch, attcahing screenshot, in the attachment you can see business date is first key but when i console th response it got sort in alphabatical order.
[image]

Comment: If you want to keep the order, you should use an array. An Object doesn’t have an ‘order’.

Answer (score 1):

You can not, so, I think the only solution is using an array called, e.g. "orderKeys".

If you get it, you can use some like:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of data">
  <div *ngFor="let key of orderKeys">
     {{element[key]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

If you has the object create, you can get the "orderKeys" by

```
orderKeys=JSON.stringify(this.myobj)
   .replace(/((:\[(.*?)\])|
             (:{(.*?)})|
             (:\b(\w*)\b)|
             (:\"\b(\w*)\b)|
             {|
             }|\")/g,"").split(',')
```

else, you need create it yourself

Answer (score 0):

it's sort by browser,not angular. Blue `i` icon inform about it.

Comment: Yes i undertand it, but while looping it on angular it is still printing in alphabatical order on webpage